# Conformal Automorphisms from punctured unit square to punctured unit square

Tags: complex-analysis

Let the punctured unit square be defined as $$\Omega = \{z \in \mathbb{C}: \mid Re(z)\mid \lt 1, \mid Im(z) \mid \lt 1 \} \setminus \{0\}$$

Determine all conformal automorphisms (i.e. biholomorphism) of $\Omega$ which maps $\frac{1}{2}$ to $\frac{1}{2}$. What if the requirement mapping $\frac{1}{2}$ to $\frac{1}{2}$ is removed?

I believe that only the identity map can meet the requirements. I am thinking of arguing by some smoothness property at the corner, but not sure how to get it work.

Answer (score 0):

A hint:

Begin by solving the same problem for the punctured unit disk instead of a square.

Second hint:

The Riemann mapping theorem guarantees the existence of a conformal map $\psi$ of the full square to the unit disk such that $\psi(0)=0$. (One could write down $\psi$ explicitly, but this is not needed for your proof.)

Comment: Thanks. But how are they connected? I can easily solve the version for the unit disk.